# Find moving points in 2d space near some point

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry

I have a lot of points in a 2d space. Each point moves with a constant speed and direction every time unit. Given the location, speed and direction of points at t=0, I am looking for the most efficient way to look up or calculate all points within radius R from a given point P at any t=T. T can only increase (or stay the same) after each query.

What data structure or way would be good for this?

I was thinking I could use a space dividing tree so that I can quickly (log time) find points in the nearby area and then check those all by distance. But the problems with that would be that I would have to somehow change or recreate the tree for every next T, because the points have moved.

Is there a way to take advantage of the constant movement, or at least of the fact that points only move relatively little between every time step to create a more efficient solution?

(If an appropriate solution can be created much more efficiently I would love to hear about that as well)

For clarification, I need:

```cs
Datastructure<MovingPoint> points = ...;

Set<MovingPoint> getPointsNear(MovingPoint centerPoint, float radius, ulong time) {
    // some code that finds the points near centerPoint at t='time'
    // using whatever datastructure we used to store the points in.
    // MovingPoints have a PosT0, Speed and Direction vectors, and .getPos(ulong t)
    // will get you the position of that point at time t.
    ...
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi! Interesting problem. *"I was thinking I could use a space dividing tree"* Yes, great idea. This is usually called a "quadtree" in 2d. *"But the problems with that would be that I would have to somehow change or recreate the tree for every next T, because the points have moved."* Indeed. I've never worked with moving point clouds, but searching for "quad tree when points are moving" or "dynamic quadtree" brings up a lot of results, and in particular a lot of questions on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: *"Is there a way to take advantage of the constant movement, or at least of the fact that points only move relatively little between every time step to create a more efficient solution?"* Instead of a quadtree, you could use a simple grid. With the cell sidelength just large enough that a point can only remain in the same cell or move to an adjacent cell in the grid in one timestep. Updating a grid seems easier than updating a tree. Depending on the ratio R / c, where c is sidelength of a cell and R is your radius, you might only need to check a few cells to get all points within radius R.

Comment: @Stef thank you for the suggestion, those sound nice, but there is still a problem. Lets say I have many points, but I only need to check a single point every T. Using quad trees or grid I would still have to calculate the leaf/cell for all points every T. The main improvement I am wondering is possible would be somehow preventing having to go over every far away point every T. From one of the answers you mentioned I realize I could use a quad tree and only update any points currently at a reasonable distance from the point to check. That's the best I got so far, can we do even better?

Comment: Is the direction also constant? I mean points are passing by in a straight line?

Comment: Yes the direction is also constant. That is also why it would be fine to not update points for a long time and then only update them when needed for a nearby query. And why I was wondering if there is a better solution

Comment: Waiiiiit are all points moving in the same direction and at the same speed? In that case their relative position doesn't change at all!

Comment: You could also just extend your search radius and search without updating the structure. If you want to find all points that are at distance at most R, but you know that points can have moved up to a distance D since last update, then search instead for points at distance at most D+R, and then examine each of these candidates to filter out those that are not really at distance at most R.

Comment: Can we assume that R and P are constant?

Comment: @btilly no R and P are not constant, they can change every query (though in practice R will probably barely ever change, so you could assume R is constant if you like)

Comment: @Stef No, all points are not moving in the same direction and speed, every point has its own direction and speed. Per point the direction and speed are constant, but this does mean the relative distance changes over time.

Comment: @Stef, your comment did make me realize something that might be useful: per set of 2 points you could calculate how far they move to/from each other over time and then use that to help with the search. Such a distance over time function between 2 points would probably be a quadratic function of some kind (I'm not a huge math guy, but that's my guess) but maybe this can still be used in some way? At the very least this could be a way to very quickly calculate distances between points.

Comment: I added an answer for constant `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that `R` is constant and we're looking for a distance of strictly `< R`

For any two points, we can try to generate an interval of time when they are within `R` of each other. There are two cases.

1. They are moving at the same velocity. If they start within `R` of each other, they are there for `(-inf, inf)`. (In practice we might just use a large number for `inf`.) Or they may not not be, in which case no interval.
2. They are moving relative to each other. If we write down the formula their separation at a time `t` and then solve for when `‖distance‖^2 = R^2` you'll get a quadratic equation. If it has two solutions `t1, t2` with `t1 < t2`, then we get an interval `(t1, t2)`. Otherwise no interval.

With `n` points we get a collection of intervals. Make a set of all points of time for which we have intervals, and throw in `-inf` and `inf` if they are not in the set. Now sort this to get a list of time points.

(Note, we've so far used at most `O(n^2)` memory and `O(n^2 log(n))` time.)

Now let's organize this into a search tree. First we add the midpoint between finite numbers. Then recursively split the list on midpoints, associating each with the interval that gets there. If there is a choice of midpoints, avoid infinity.

Here's a quick example to show what I mean.

Suppose that the set of time points is `[-inf, -5, -2, 0, 3, 9, inf]`.

We add the separating points to get `[-inf, -5, -3.5, -2, -1, 0, 1.5, 3, 6, 9, inf]`.

The search tree (drawn sideways for space) would be

```
        -inf: (-inf, -5)
    -5: (-inf, 0)
            -3.5: (-5, 2)
        -2: (-5, 0)
            -1: (-2, 0)
0: (-inf, inf)
            1.5: (0, 3)
        3: (0, 9)
            6: (3, 9)
    9: (0, inf)
        inf: (9, inf)
```

Now to each node in this tree we will add an empty dictionary from a point, to a list of points that are within `R` for the whole interval. Then we start adding following this logic.

```
If p, q are within R for (t1, t2):
    Start at the root and recursively add as follows:
        at node s: (s1, s2)
            if t1 <= s1 and s2 <= t2:
                add p to the list within R of q
                add q to the list within R of p
            else:
                if t1 < s:
                    recursively add to the left node
                if s < t2:
                    recursively add to the right node
```

This will take time `O(log(n))`. It will add the fact that `p` is within `R` of `q` to at most `O(log(n))` nodes. It will add the fact that `q` is within `R` of `p` to the same nodes.

Now to do a query of `P` at time `t` we will visit `O(log(n))` nodes in this tree. At each node we'll look in the dictionary. If `p` is in the dictionary, we add the nodes in its list to the answer. By construction, we'll get no duplicates in our final list. A lookup will therefore take `O(log(n) + k)` where `k` is the number of other points in our answer.

If we want a distance of `<= R`, we only need add a dictionary, by time, of which relatively moving points are **exactly** `R` apart.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a great idea! While this makes the queries very fast, the downside is the O(n^2) calculation that has to be done at the start, which would take quite a while if there are very many points. I think I will see if I can combine the idea of this answer with a grid or quad tree such that I do not have to do that calculation for every combination of points, but only for points in a reasonably close distance, and then recalculate the nearby combinations every once in a while.

Comment: Either way, the idea of this solution is great for the problem I had, so I will accept this answer

Comment: @Koen If you are only interested in queries in a particular region, you can in `O(n)` time find out when each is in that region, and then only compare each point with other points in the region of interest at the same time.